# what do we mean by $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Tags: probability

when we say $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ for instance, do we refer to the p.d.f or the c.d.f?

Comment: Both. It refers to the distribution which is characterised by either the cdf. or the pdf.

Comment: Is it wrong to say "$\mathcal{N}(0,1) =_d$ >>insert pdf/cdf of standard normal distribution<<" ?

Comment: When you write $=_d$ it means two random variables are equal in distribution. ${\cal N}(0,1)$ refers to a distribution not a random variable.

Comment: How about if i write "=". ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is the following statement correct:

$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{(\frac{x^2}{2})}$

Comment: It is hard to read.

Comment: It is readable now.

Comment: Not really. As I said above, it refers to the distribution, not the cdf. If I write $X \sim {\cal N}(0,1)$ it means that $X$ has a standard normal distribution and the cdf. of $X$ is $\Phi$.

Comment: Why does it matter???

Comment: When I see a notation like $X \sim \text{something}$, I think of a machine with a button and an output. When you press the button, it produces a random output, and the "rule" for this random output is this $\text{something}$. It's sort of a method of producing the random numbers. But ultimately we can't say exactly what the output is, that's why it's random. Then there's something like $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$, which is a function. Nothing random here. But when we gather data from $X$, we see that the frequencies of outputs look a little bit like $f(x)$.